# problem with resizing partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, fdisk

I', trying to resize my partition to the maximum space available, I tried different tools and got the same result. 
The latest one is growpart. 
The problem is that all the process seems to work, and the partition size is changed, however when I type `df -h`, I get the following result:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p2  3.1G  1.2G  1.9G  39% /
devtmpfs        360M     0  360M   0% /dev
tmpfs           489M     0  489M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           489M   20M  470M   4% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           489M     0  489M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1   40M   16M   25M  40% /boot
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs            98M     0   98M   0% /run/user/0
```

and when I type `fdisk -l` i get the following:

```
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 7.4 GiB, 7948206080 bytes, 15523840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x66dc81bc

Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1       49152   131071    81920   40M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p2      131072 15523806 15392735  7.3G 83 Linux
```

the `growpart` command result is:

```
CHANGED: partition=2 start=131072 old: size=7486114 end=7617186 new: size=15392735,end=15523807
```

of course, I did a reboot, and still didn't help.

any idea what's going wrong?

I'm stuck for 4 days in this part. 
P.S. this process must be done in a script for our product porpuses.

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: I have found a good tutorial which helped me with resizing OrangePi SDCard with Armbian https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:Expanding_File_System_Partition_On_A_microSD

Answer (score 2):

Did you resize the filesystem? I don't think command line partitioning tools do this step automatically.

To resize a the filesystem to fill the partition:

```
resize2fs /dev/YOUR_DEVICE
```

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: Here is the result of resize2fs :
Filesystem at /dev/mmcblk0p2 is mounted on /;

on-line resizing required old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 1 Performing an on-line resize of /dev/mmcblk0p2 to 1924096 (4k) blocks.

Comment: I don't see any error message in there. And the size seems to be correct. I'm afraid I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: How you explain the difference between the df result which says that p2.partition is 3.1gig and the fdisk.result which says p2 is 7.3gig. My sd card is ~8gig.

Comment: 1924096 * 4k is about 7.3 GiB, which is what we want the file system to be, since the partition was expanded to that size. As for the discrepancy  between 7.3 and 8, the units are different. 8 GB is about 7.4 GiB, minus some for the first partition, then some rounding.

Comment: Please note that the result of the command "df" says it was expanded to 3.1GB, and the fact is that i can't save a file that exceed the size of 3.1Gb means that the actual partition size is 3.1Gb and not 7.3Gb. 

One more note, before i did the resizing the size of the partition was 1.8Gb, Which mean that the commands did a resizing but not to the max available size.

Comment: You are still mixing up the partition with the filesystem, and you are mixing up units: GiB, GB, and Gb are not the same. To clarify, here's my understanding. `fdisk` shows the size of the partition, which is 7.3 GiB. `df` shows the size of the filesystem, which is 3.1 GiB. Now `resize2fs` seems to say it resized you filesystem to 7.3 GiB, which is what you want, and there is no discernible error message in what you copied here. I have nothing else to say but, go check again.

Comment: Regarding the units, I always meant Gigabyte ( i will start using GiB). I understand the difference between the partition size and the filesystem. What i'm trying to do is to enlarge the filesystem the size of the available free space in partition. I need that df shows me 7.3GiB, so my question is what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to resize a *mounted* partition. You will have to boot from a LiveUSB or LiveCD, not from the disk you're trying to resize.

Search the Internet for "Gparted Live", ( https://gparted.org/livecd.php ) and you'll find a distribution for your hardware. Using `gparted` to move/resize partitions takes care of the `resiz2fs`. I have successfully resized partitions on two systems with `gparted`.

Comment: I must do that on script not with UI. The resize is done, but it change the size for 3.1G instead of 7.3G